# Running server and client through a single maven command

Tags: maven

I have to run a server application( in background) and client application through a single maven command. Is it possible?

Comment: Are there any relations between server app & client app ?
Could you give more detail.

Comment: Why you wanna lauch your application via Maven ? However, it's possible by customizing your own Maven plugin, see here:http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html